# Cutscene Scripting for CameraController

Tags: unity, c#, camera

I have a `CameraController` script which follows a `GameController` if it's present in the scene.

How can I add cutscene animator to `CameraController`? Should I use a separate script for my `CutsceneCamera`?

Here is my `CameraController`:

```
int ActivePresetIndex = -1;
public CameraPreset ActivePreset { get; private set; }

CarController TargetCar { get { return OverrideCar?? GameController.PlayerCar; } }
GameController GameController { get { return GameController.Instance; } }

float SqrMinDistance;
int CurrentFrame = 0;

//The target point is calculated from velocity of car.
Vector3 m_TargetPoint;
Vector3 TargetPoint
{
    get
    {
        if (CurrentFrame != Time.frameCount)
        {
            if (!OverrideCar && GameController == null || TargetCar == null)
            {
                return transform.position;
            }
            m_TargetPoint = TargetCar.RB.velocity * ActivePreset.VelocityMultiplier;
            m_TargetPoint += TargetCar.transform.position;

            CurrentFrame = Time.frameCount;
        }
        return m_TargetPoint;
    }
}

protected override void AwakeSingleton ()
{
    CamerasPreset.ForEach (c => c.CameraHolder.SetActive (false));

    ActivePresetIndex = GameOptions.ActiveCameraIndex;
    UpdateActiveCamera ();
}

private IEnumerator Start ()
{
    while (!OverrideCar && (GameController == null || TargetCar == null))
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    transform.position = TargetPoint;
    ActivePreset.CameraHolder.rotation = TargetCar.transform.rotation;
}

private void Update ()
{
    if (ActivePreset.EnableRotation)
    {
        var position = transform.position.ZeroHeight ();
        var target = TargetPoint.ZeroHeight ();

        if ((position - target).sqrMagnitude >= SqrMinDistance)
        {
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (target - position, Vector3.up);
            ActivePreset.CameraHolder.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (ActivePreset.CameraHolder.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * ActivePreset.SetRotationSpeed);
        }
    }

    transform.position = Vector3.LerpUnclamped (transform.position, TargetPoint, Time.deltaTime * ActivePreset.SetPositionSpeed);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.C) || Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Joystick1Button2))
    {
        SetNextCamera ();
    }
}

public void SetNextCamera ()
{
    ActivePresetIndex = MathExtentions.LoopClamp (ActivePresetIndex + 1, 0, CamerasPreset.Count);
    GameOptions.ActiveCameraIndex = ActivePresetIndex;
    UpdateActiveCamera ();
}

public void UpdateActiveCamera ()
{
    if (ActivePreset != null)
    {
        ActivePreset.CameraHolder.SetActive (false);
    }

    ActivePreset = CamerasPreset[ActivePresetIndex];
    ActivePreset.CameraHolder.SetActive (true);

    SqrMinDistance = ActivePreset.MinDistanceForRotation * 2;

    if (ActivePreset.EnableRotation && (TargetPoint - transform.position).sqrMagnitude >= SqrMinDistance)
    {
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (TargetPoint - transform.position, Vector3.up);
        ActivePreset.CameraHolder.rotation = rotation;
    }
}

private void OnDrawGizmosSelected ()
{
    if (Application.isPlaying)
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (TargetPoint, 1);
        Gizmos.color = Color.white;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class CameraPreset
{
    public Transform CameraHolder;                  //Parent fo camera.
    public float SetPositionSpeed = 1;              //Change position speed.
    public float VelocityMultiplier;                //Velocity of car multiplier.

    public bool EnableRotation;
    public float MinDistanceForRotation = 0.1f;     //Min distance for potation, To avoid uncontrolled rotation.
    public float SetRotationSpeed = 1;              //Change rotation speed.
}
```

And here is how I trigger my cutscene:

```
public class CutSceneEnter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject CameraController;
    public GameObject cutsceneCam;

    void onTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
       cutsceneCam.SetActive(true);
       CameraController.SetActive(false);
    }   
}
```

Comment: What do you want your camera to do during the cutscene? That's not clear to me from reading this question. Your suggestion to make a separate script to control the camera during the cutscene sounds sensible: how have you tried implementing this idea so far, and where did you run into trouble that we can help you overcome?

Comment: @DMGregory I have small project racing game and racing has start with cameraController.I created a maincamera including animator in scene for intro before race start.Also cameracontroller prefap is seperate so not included in scene.When I play button race has start but not showing intro,which I am created MainCamera.If you want I will record a video.

Comment: How exactly did you make that cutscene? Did you use a [timeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/TimelineSection.html)?

Comment: @Philipp Yes, I use timeline and added in to MainCamera.I recorded a video a month ago.https://youtu.be/kAtMLaZiMo8